# MultiQC snakemake wrapper: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'imp'

Tags: python, snakemake

I am running FastQC and MultiQC in my `snakemake` pipeline:

```
rule fastqc:
    input:
        "reads/{sample}_trimmed.fq.gz"
    output:
        html="qc/fastqc/{sample}.html",
        zip="qc/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.zip" # the suffix _fastqc.zip is necessary for multiqc to find the file
    params:
        extra = "--quiet"
    log:
        "logs/fastqc/{sample}.log"
    threads: config["resources"]["fastqc"]["cpu"]
    resources:
        runtime=config["resources"]["fastqc"]["time"]
    wrapper:
        "v1.31.1/bio/fastqc"


rule multiqc:
    input:
        expand("qc/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.zip", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        report("qc/multiqc.html", caption="workflow/report/multiqc.rst", category="MultiQC analysis of fastq files")
    params:
        extra="",  # Optional: extra parameters for multiqc.
        use_input_files_only=True, # Optional, use only a.txt and don't search folder samtools_stats for files
    resources:
        runtime=config["resources"]["fastqc"]["time"]
    log:
        "logs/multiqc/multiqc.log"
    wrapper:
        "v1.31.1/bio/multiqc"
```

The fastqc rule runs without any issues, but multiqc fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/db6c33339e73e6beea68618300022717_/bin/multiqc", line 6, in <module>
    from multiqc.__main__ import run_multiqc
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/db6c33339e73e6beea68618300022717_/lib/python3.12/site-packages/multiqc/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .multiqc import run
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/db6c33339e73e6beea68618300022717_/lib/python3.12/site-packages/multiqc/multiqc.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .plots import table
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/db6c33339e73e6beea68618300022717_/lib/python3.12/site-packages/multiqc/plots/table.py", line 9, in <module>
    from multiqc.plots import beeswarm, table_object
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/db6c33339e73e6beea68618300022717_/lib/python3.12/site-packages/multiqc/plots/beeswarm.py", line 8, in <module>
    from multiqc.plots import table_object
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/db6c33339e73e6beea68618300022717_/lib/python3.12/site-packages/multiqc/plots/table_object.py", line 9, in <module>
    from multiqc.utils import config, report
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/db6c33339e73e6beea68618300022717_/lib/python3.12/site-packages/multiqc/utils/report.py", line 18, in <module>
    import lzstring
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/db6c33339e73e6beea68618300022717_/lib/python3.12/site-packages/lzstring/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from future import standard_library
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/db6c33339e73e6beea68618300022717_/lib/python3.12/site-packages/future/standard_library/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    import imp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
```

Using a later version of the wrapper (v2.6.0) gives me the same error. The multiqc rule has worked before, so I don't understand why `imp` is not found suddenly.

The yaml file to create the conda env for the multiqc wrapper:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - multiqc =1.16
```

A quick Internet search tells me that ["The imp module includes functions that expose part of the underlying implementation of Python’s import mechanism for loading code in packages and modules"](http://pymotw.com/2/imp/) , and seems to me already a part of Python?

Comment: No issues in snakemake or snakemake-wrappers.  Can you provide your version of snakemake and try a different version?  Only other thing I see is a version bump of multiqc from 1.15 to 1.16 in the [wrapper](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/commit/ecc45e819f5e72b71ee777fa336da8c61a84758c).

Comment: I'm running in the same issue using the Snakemake MultiQC wrapper (v2.6.0/bio/multiqc). I'm guessing that it's directly related to the python version, that is installed. My standard python installation has version==3.9.7, which still allows the import of imp. However, the wrapper creates an environment with python version==3.12.0, thus not incuding the imp module anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `imp` module is [deprecated in favor of importlib, and removed from the standard library since python version 3.12.0](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/imp.html).
Thus, depending on the python version your program-call/conda-environment is using, you will encounter a `ModuleNotFoundError` Error.

A quick workaround can be to simply fix the used python on a version<3.12.0.

Here's what I did:

**multiqc_env.yaml**

```
name: multiqc_env
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
  - default
dependencies:
  - python<3.12
  - multiqc
```

**multiqc.smk**

```
rule run_multiqc:
  input: 
    some_input_file
  output:
    some_output_file
  params:
    extra="-d",
    output_dir=lambda wildcards, output: os.path.dirname(output[0]),
    output_file_name=lambda wildcards, output: os.path.basename(output[0]),
    input_directories=lambda wildcards, input: set(os.path.dirname(fp) for fp in input)
  log:
    ...
  conda:
    "multiqc_env.yaml"
  shell:
    "multiqc {params.extra} --force "
    "-o {params.output_dir} -n {params.output_file_name} "
    "{params.input_directories} &> {log}"
```

In my case Conda installed a python `version=3.11.6`, and this made MultiQC run again.

Hope this helps :)